# CudafyModule km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(); COMPILATION ERROR

Tags: c#, cudafy.net

im trying to get better performance on my algorithm, so im trying cudafy for that. Already done a lot of tutorials but it still miss something.

Here the error that occur:

Compilation error: C:/Users/Nuno/Desktop/KuhnPokerFinal/KuhnPokerFinal/bin/Debug/CUDAFYSOURCETEMP.cu(10): error: identifier "random" is undefined

1 error detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/Nuno/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00002724_00000000-8_CUDAFYSOURCETEMP.cpp1.ii".enter code here

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and suggest that the identifier "random" might be undefined.

Comment: Maybe you can observe my question, too, might be a similiar problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531171/cudafy-struct-undefined-in-nested-struct